# How to build a list sequence containing multiple nested sequences with a loop?

Tags: python

```
list1 = [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]

element = [list1[0], list1[1]]; list2.append(element)
element = [list1[2], list1[3]]; list2.append(element)
```

The two `list2.append(element)` lines above create a two-sequence list with each sequence containing two nested sequences.  The result of "print list2" is below:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
[[5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

List 2 is what I want.  But my question is how do I build list2 using a loop?  I see the append and insert commands but they don't seem to create multiple elements separated by commas in the same sequence.

Answer (score 3):

```
zip(list1[::2], list1[1::2])
```

The first argument is all the even elements, and the second argument is all the odd elements. Zip those and you're done.

Comment: or `map(list, zip(list1[::2], list1[1::2]))` if you want lists instead of tuples.

Comment: Thank you.  That's a very good answer.  But I gave a very simple example I hope? might be well served with a loop.  The real-world list1 would have many more sequences.  Additionally, I may write more than two list1 sequences into a list2 sequence.  And the list1 sequences are seldom consecutive.

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was incomplete.  The number of list1 elements and order may well differ by list2 sequence may well differ.  For instance, assume 10 list1 sequences.  I may write list1 sequences 1 + 2 to the 1st list2 sequence.  However, the 2nd list2 sequence may have list1 sequences 1 + 3 + 8.

Comment: Golly, again with the incomplete comment.  Sorry.  Let me try one more time.  The number of elements I write to list2 sequences will differ and the order of elements I choose by sequence from list1 will differ.  Basically, what I want is a list command that will append elements to the same sequence.  I can easily write a loop to do that, but it creates multiple sequences.  I want to append/insert to the same sequence until I request a new sequence to be written.  I see zips usefullness.  Maybe that's the best way, but is there a list command that appends/inserts to the same sequence?

Comment: You should probably create a new question with a further elaborated example, since my answer is probably the most applicable to the original question.

Comment: Thank you, but I think I figured it out.  Assuming I want to add an element to the second list2 sequence:  list2[1].insert(len(list2[1]),'NewElement').  I can easily modify that to fit my loop.  I could swear I tried that prior to posting my question without success.  Regardless, the process of writing/re-writing my question made it clear.